# Optimize code - create custom text view from array and assign value

Tags: android

This code generate some textview and assign value to it using an array.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_list);

    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llContainer2);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int textViewCount = 24;
    TextView[] pairs=new TextView[textViewCount];
    for(int i=0; i<textViewCount; i++)
    {
        pairs[i] = new TextView(this);
        pairs[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
        pairs[i].setId(i);

        pairs[i].setText(getString(R.string.t1));
        //--------------------
        pairs[i].setClickable(true);
        pairs[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        pairs[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4682B4"));
        pairs[i].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 21);
        pairs[i].setPadding(8,8,8,8);
        //------------------
        myLayout.addView(pairs[i]);
}}
```

I found these codes inside //-- and //-- is repeatative.
I am finding way to optimise it.
My thinking
 1. inflate textview layout inside the loop and using a customlayout.xml 
 2. set the layout once on the start, so it inherent the layout from parent

Tried

> LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
>       (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>
> View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.style_textview, null);
>
> myLayout.addView(child);
>
> //------------------------------
>
> LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)
>   findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
>
> View inflatedLayout= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.style_textview, null);
>
> container.addView(inflatedLayout);

Anyone can show me how to use the xml inside loop or inflate the parent.

Secondly, how to use

> ```
> public void onClick(View v) {
>         switch (v.getId()){ 
>             case R.id.i:
>                 //start activity
> }}
> ```

I am open to better suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inflate the view like this:

```
pairs[i] = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout. style_textview, myLayout, false);

// Don't set Id by a code-defined value like this, use setTag for additional data or use View.generateViewId()
pairs[i].setId(i);

pairs[i].setText(getString(R.string.t1));
pairs[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
myLayout.addView(pairs[i]);
```

`LayoutParams` and other properties are defined in xml

Comment: The inflater does work, thank you.
Do you know how to set onclicklistener and onclick (view v) based on this created textview? I cant get the id

Comment: Check my edited answer. The simplest way is to use anonymous inner class. Or you make it a separate class link `TextViewClickListener` and `setOnClickListener(new TextViewClickListener(i)) here

Comment: Glad I can help